# Use MenulinkTree::load in page_preprocess

Tags: 8, theming

I'm on drupal 8, and i want to get menu links from the main menu in order to create the same menu for mobile (so i need 2 same menu, with differents rendering)

I use like this :

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['menu'] = \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTree::load('main');
}
```

But it's broke my website.

What do you think about that ?

Comment: First thing is that you can use `\Drupal::menuTree()` service instead of calling it statically. Second, I guess this is not the way to get what you want to achieve. Checkout https://www.drupal.org/node/2226481.

Comment: I never understand why people do this - duplicating content on a page is bad for several reasons, and all devices that you'd target for this behaviour have javascript enabled. Why not use javascript to manipulate the existing markup at page load? You can use CSS + media queries to hide things until they're ready for display.

Comment: thanks to yours answers. @Clive i think it's a good solution to use JS

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't use a second (mandatory) parameter. Look at this example:

```
$menu_name = 'main';
$menu_tree_service = \Drupal::service('menu.link_tree');
$menu_parameters = new \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters();
$menu_parameters->setMaxDepth(1);
$tree = $menu_tree_service->load($menu_name, $menu_parameters);
```

You could also set a root menu item like this:

```
$menu_parameters->setRoot($root_menu_item->getPluginId());
```

To get the menu link title and url:

```
foreach ($tree as $item) {
  $title = $item->link->getTitle();
  $url = $item->link->getUrlObject()->toString();
}
```